# FONET/FOP superscript; inline-container not showing up at all

Tags: pdf, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I'm developing a FONET app to generate some simple PDF reports; got everything working except the client would like the registered trademark symbol raised up correctly to superscript level.

I tried `text-altitude` on an inline element with no success, so after digging around the internet's woeful XSL:FO documentation thought I needed to wrap that in an `fo:inline-container`. However, that does not show up at all.

I've cut it down by using this [basic example](http://www.herongyang.com/XSL-FO/Inline-What-Is-inline-container-Formatting-Object.html):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- inline-container-Converts-Block-to-Inline.fo
 - Copyright (c) 2016, HerongYang.com, All Rights Reserved.
-->
<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
 <fo:layout-master-set>
  <fo:simple-page-master master-name="page" 
   margin="0.1in" page-height="4in" page-width="3in">
   <fo:region-body region-name="body" background-color="#eeeeee"/>
  </fo:simple-page-master>
 </fo:layout-master-set>
 <fo:page-sequence master-reference="page">
  <fo:flow flow-name="body">
   <fo:block margin="0.1in" padding="0.2in"
    border-width="1px" border-style="solid"
    background-color="#eeffff" color="#000000" 
    font-family="sans-serif" font-size="10pt">
    Once upon a time
    <fo:inline-container width="0.7in" margin="0in" 
     alignment-baseline="middle">
    <fo:block background-color="#eeeeee" margin="0in"
     border-width="1px" border-style="solid"
     padding="4px">there were three little pigs</fo:block>
    </fo:inline-container>
    who lived with their Mother.
    Early one morning they woke up and their mother said, 
    "<fo:inline font-style="italic" color="#ff22ff">you're too big
    for this house and its time you left home.</fo:inline>"
   </fo:block>
  </fo:flow>
 </fo:page-sequence>
</fo:root>
```

and tried to run that, but this also does not display anything from the `inline-container`; tried in [this online processor](http://www.utilities-online.info/foprender/) and that also doesn't show anything from the container, so not just a FONET issue.

FONET is a port of FOP 0.2, which [should have basic support](https://www.cs.helsinki.fi/group/xmltools/formatters/fop/fop-0.20.5/build/site/compliance.html#fo-property-text-altitude) for both `text-altitude` and `inline-container`.

What am I missing? Is it possible to get a superscript effect in this version of FOP?

Answer (score 3):

The conformance page that you link to shows that `fo:inline-container` is not supported.  It still has only partial support in the latest FOP (https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/compliance.html).

I assume that it's because you were trying things to get it to work, but putting "there were three little pigs" in a space 0.7in wide makes for a tall and narrow area from the `fo:inline-container`.

The good news is that you don't need `fo:inline-container` to make a superscript.  Just use an `fo:inline` with `baseline-shift="super"` (see https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#baseline-shift).

You may also want to consider both reducing the `font-size` for the superscript text (since the FO formatter won't assume that you also want that) and adding `line-height-shift-adjustment="disregard-shifts"` (see https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#line-height-shift-adjustment) on an ancestor FO so that the superscript doesn't alter your line height:

```
<fo:block line-height-shift-adjustment="disregard-shifts"
      margin="0.1in" padding="0.2in"
      border-width="1px" border-style="solid"
      background-color="#eeffff" color="#000000" 
      font-family="sans-serif" font-size="10pt">
  Once upon a time<fo:inline
    baseline-shift="super" font-size="0.8em">®</fo:inline>
  there were three little pigs<fo:inline
    baseline-shift="super" font-size="0.8em">®</fo:inline>
  who lived with their Mother.
  Early one morning they woke up and their mother said, 
  "<fo:inline font-style="italic" color="#ff22ff">you're too big
  for this house and its time you left home.</fo:inline>"
</fo:block>
```

Also see "Character style setting" in the "Comprehensive XSL-FO Tutorials and Samples Collection" at https://www.antennahouse.com/antenna1/comprehensive-xsl-fo-tutorials-and-samples-collection/

---

The last resort, when your FO formatter does not implement `baseline-shift`, is to find a font with a superscript-looking registered trademark symbol. A quick trawl through the Windows 'Character Map' utility showed that 'Calibri' has one.

Comment: Unfortunately, although baseline-shift works perfectly in that online FOP 1.0 processor, it is not in FOP 0.2, which the .NET library is a port of, so it does not work in my code. Do you have any other tricks for superscripting?

Comment: Sorry, no.  `baseline-shift` is the property that is designed for achieving superscripts.  Your only hope is to find a font with a superscript-looking registered trademark symbol.  A quick trawl through the Windows 'Character Map' utility showed that 'Calibri' has one.  There may be others.  Alternatively, you could try a different FO formatter that implements more of XSL 1.1.

Comment: Apache FOP 0,2.5 was released 18 Jul 2003. That is more than 14 years ago. You would do yourself a real service to use software maybe developed in the past few years and not a decade or two ago.

Comment: @KevinBrown Plenty of old software does exactly what you need, and this does everything I currently need except superscript. I am limited to 0.2 because the .NET port stopped at that version.

Comment: @TonyGraham I didn't think of that, I'll give Calibri a try, thanks!

Comment: @TonyGraham - using Calibri worked, thanks! Make your comment an answer and I'll mark it as such.